# Flutter: Add ReorderableList inside a ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

The issue I have is adding a `ReorderableList` inside a `ListView`, the `ReorderableList` does not allow for reordering now. I can scroll the list but the long press for reodering is not active anymore. Here is my code:

```
Widget get _reorder => ReorderableList(
    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => _cells[index],
    itemCount: _cells?.length ?? 0,
    onReorder: _setListOrder,
  );

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  decoration: context.logoBackground,
  child: SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 1,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    _reorder,
                    Text('End of List Widget')
                  ],
                );
              }),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it with `ReorderableListView` instead of `ReorderableList` like this:

```dart
void _setListOrder(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
    print('old: $oldIndex, new: $newIndex'); // You need to implement the method!
  }

  var _cells = List.generate(30, (index) { // Your cells
    return ListTile(
      key: Key('$index'),
      title: Text(
        '$index',
      ),
    );
  });

  Widget get _reorder => ReorderableListView.builder(
        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => _cells[index],
        itemCount: _cells?.length ?? 0,
        onReorder: _setListOrder,
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: ListView( // I transformed it to simple ListView because you have one children
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, // You need this height, or a custom height!
                            child: _reorder),
                        Text('End of List Widget')
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

If you want to check the documentation, you can do it [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView-class.html)!

Comment: Works, thanks. I believe it has something to do with wrapping the reorder in a container and settings height

Comment: I do however have a large gap between my listview of cells and my Text widget. Any idea on how to solve that?